# Converting an existing Tor relay into a bridge, does it make sense?

Tags: bridge, censorship

I have been running a relay for a couple of years. Now I see that with my connection bandwidth of 1 Mbit it makes more sense to run a bridge.

I could just convert my relay into a bridge. However, I am concerned that such a bridge will not be accessible from places where Tor is blocked because its IP address might have been blacklisted as running a relay.

Can anyone confirm or disprove this concern from their own experience or knowledge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Your IP address is tainted and not suitable to host a bridge.
Even if it is not blocked, it is still unsafe to connect to your IP for people who need bridges.

Comment: Even if I have never ever been a guard?

Answer (score 0):

This is not to be concerned seriously : blacklist era is gone with AtGuard :) But you should strongly consider running OBFSproxy on your relay, try obfs3 on 443 port. I'm running a mixed config myself, upgraded to bridge - and it seems that many people are using it. IP haven't been changed, of course

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you pelase elaborate on AtGuard?

Comment: @ilya In times of AtGuard you've just had an IP blacklist in dot-txt file, usually, and - just loaded it into the program.